# Boolean value is not recognized when using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using SQL in snowflake. I am trying to use CASE WHEN to develop indicators for smoking status. When I run the code, I get an error:

> Boolean value '428061000124105' is not recognized.

The code I am using is:

```sql
SELECT 
  history.PATIENT_ID as pat,
  history.SMOKING_STATUS AS smoke,
 CASE
  WHEN smoke = '428061000124105' OR '428071000124103' THEN 'smoker'
  WHEN smoke = '8517006' THEN 'ex_smoker'
ELSE 'NA'
END AS smoking_status
FROM 'db'.'schema'.'table';
```

Is this a data issue? What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: `WHEN smoke IN ('428061000124105', '428071000124103') THEN 'smoker'`

Comment: Or `WHEN smoke = '428061000124105' OR smoke = '428071000124103' THEN 'smoker'`

Comment: `FROM 'db'.'schema'.'table';` isn't going to work, single quotes (`'`) are for literal strings, not delimit identifying objects.

Comment: What kind of values are in **history.SMOKING_STATUS** ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are providing column name only in when condition, SQL server is interpreting it as a boolean value.

Please try changing it to WHEN smoke = '428061000124105' OR smoke = '428071000124103' THEN 'smoker'

Answer (score 0):

This might show why the error is happening:

```
SELECT column1 as smoke
    ,CASE 
        WHEN smoke = '1234' THEN 'booleans are equal to text represntations of numbers'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END as smoke_test
FROM VALUES (true), (false);
```

gives:

> Boolean value '1234' is not recognized

This is say, "you have a boolean value" (aka only true or false) and you are comparing it to a string. Don't do that.

If you insist of comparing 'true' or 'false' to text numbers. You can cast the boolean to a TEXT

```
SELECT column1 as smoke
    ,CASE 
        WHEN smoke::text = '1234' THEN 'booleans are equal to text represntations of numbers'
        WHEN smoke::text = '1' THEN 'one'
        WHEN smoke::text = '0' THEN 'zero'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END as smoke_test
FROM VALUES (true), (false);
```

| SMOKE | SMOKE_TEST |
| --- | --- |
| TRUE | NA |
| FALSE | NA |

which is the same as

```
SELECT column1 as smoke
    ,'NA'as smoke_test
FROM VALUES (true), (false);
```

or you can cast bool to INT at which point the TEXT and NUMBER compare will do an auto cast to TEXT after turning BOOL so a `null,0,1`

```
SELECT column1 as smoke
    ,CASE 
        WHEN smoke::int = '1234' THEN 'booleans are equal to text represntations of numbers'
        WHEN smoke::int = '1' THEN 'one'
        WHEN smoke::int = '0' THEN 'zero'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END as smoke_test
FROM VALUES (true), (false), (null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is considering the **Boolean OR** statement where it is not expecting it. Kindly try   as below using 'IN'.

```sql
SELECT 
  history.PATIENT_ID as pat,
  history.SMOKING_STATUS AS smoke,
 CASE
  **WHEN smoke in ('428061000124105','428071000124103')** THEN 'smoker'
  WHEN smoke = '8517006' THEN 'ex_smoker'
ELSE 'NA'
END AS smoking_status
FROM 'db'.'schema'.'table';
```